# Can you overlap graphs in Swift playground?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

If I go to a Swift playground and run something like:

```
let xs = stride(from: -2, to: 2, by: 0.03)
let ys = xs.map { x in fmod(x,1.0) }
```

I can click on the icons in the sidebar:

[image]

and see a graph:

[image]

I'd like to see some reference values, like the x-axis:

```
let xAxis = xs.map { _ in 0 }
```

But it looks like there is no way to display the two overlapping.

```
(xAxis, ys)
```

Is there a way?